# Blazor Client Side Custom Authentication Issue after last update

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, blazor

after updating to DotnetCore3 preview9 , there's strange issue

i've to use all those lines to register my custom AuthenticationStateProvider ( 3 times )

```
services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, ApiAuthenticationStateProvider>();
services.AddScoped<ApiAuthenticationStateProvider>();
services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<ApiAuthenticationStateProvider>());
```

If I removed any one it will not authenticate using `<AuthorizeView>` in the page html but in the code section the state is authorized.

Why is that?

Update:

I use client side

```
using Blazored.LocalStorage;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace MedicalDivision.Client
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();
            services.AddAuthorizationCore();
            services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, ApiAuthenticationStateProvider>();
            services.AddScoped<ApiAuthenticationStateProvider>();
            services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<ApiAuthenticationStateProvider>()); 
            services.AddSingleton<AuthService, AuthService>();
        }

        public void Configure(IComponentsApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.AddComponent<App>("app");
        }
    }
}
```

this is the client side startup.cs i use if i remove any one from the 3 lines

error is 
`WASM: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot provide a value for property 'AuthenticationStateProvider' on type 'test.Client.Shared.MainLayout'. There is no registered service of type 'test.Client.ApiAuthenticationStateProvider`

or error `blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM: System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'test.Client.ApiAuthenticationStateProvider' has been registered.`

after updating with  **Henk Holterman** answer it works

> There is no registered service of type
>   'test.Client.ApiAuthenticationStateProvider'
>
> So your code needs an ApiAuthenticationStateProvider and the
>   AuthorizeView etc need an AuthenticationStateProvider. But they should
>   both use the same instance. That gives:

```
// register an instance of ApiAuthenticationStateProvider 
    services.AddScoped<ApiAuthenticationStateProvider>();
 // register the same instance for requests for the base class
    services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider>(
    provider => provider.GetRequiredService<ApiAuthenticationStateProvider>());
 // the rest 
    services.AddScoped<IAuthService, AuthService>();
```

only one notice to use in the same order as in the answer

Comment: Are you using server-side Blazor or client-side? Where does the Startup class used above reside ? Can you show a minimal repo of your app.

Comment: it's client side and i edit the question to provide the startup.cs file

Comment: This is not a Preview9 change.

Comment: Are you using  `@inject ApiAuthenticationStateProvider ...` anywhere?

Comment: yes in main layout

Comment: On SO you should add the error info etc to the question, comments don't count here. Use [edit]